# Javascript charts as input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts, google-visualization

I have a requirement as below.

- I need to input time series data (day data) using a graph. The data is usually like below but the profile can be changed depending upon the situation.

Right now the data is being manually entered in textboxes which makes it very difficult.

I am wondering whether there are solutions that let user draw on a chart and generate the data in the back. In other words, the user picks certain points and the profile is drawn.

[image]

Comment: where does the data entered come from? it should be possible to take the data from the source and feed directly to the chart -- interesting question though, there are [methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#methods) available on the chart, such as `getVAxisValue` and `getHAxisValue` that could be used to capture where the user clicked, but it would be difficult for the user to precisely select the correct point...

Comment: [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/drag-able-charts/retrieving-data.html) This is the closest i found but the problem is i would not be able to add any data points. @WhiteHat The data comes from a database however it needs to be edited depending upon the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see following working snippet, click on the chart to add a data point...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      "cols": [
        {"label": "x", "type": "number"},
        {"label": "y", "type": "number"}
      ]
    });

    var axisMax = 10;
    var ticks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= axisMax; i = i + 0.5) {
      ticks.push(i);
    }

    var options = {
      chartArea: {
        bottom: 64,
        height: '100%',
        left: 64,
        top: 24,
        width: '100%'
      },
      hAxis: {
        format: '0.0',
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 9
        },
        ticks: ticks,
        title: data.getColumnLabel(0),
        viewWindow: {
          min: 0,
          max: axisMax
        }
      },
      height: 600,
      legend: {
        position: 'top'
      },
      pointSize: 4,
      vAxis: {
        format: '0.0',
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 9
        },
        ticks: ticks,
        title: data.getColumnLabel(1),
        viewWindow: {
          min: 0,
          max: axisMax
        }
      }
    };

    var tableDiv = document.getElementById('table_div');
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(tableDiv);
    var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
    var chartLayout = null;

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    });
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function (sender) {
      data.addRow([
        chartLayout.getHAxisValue(sender.x),
        chartLayout.getVAxisValue(sender.y)
      ]);
      drawChart();
    });

    function drawChart() {
      chart.draw(data, options);
      table.draw(data);
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
    drawChart();
  },
  packages:['corechart', 'table']
});
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: this is an elegant solution. I will need to refactor the code for my purpose. I also need to add drag over on the points.