# Online user editable pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

Is it possible to create pie chart using HTML and js/jQuery where the user can update the value by clicking on the chart? I know chart can be displayed but I'm looking for a way for the user to change the values.

Comment: although not a pie chart, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601480/5090771), which could be changed to a different chart type...

Comment: That's interesting, I'll take a look. Thanks WhiteHat